# AG-Grid Rendering not smooth in Safari 16.x

Tags: safari, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are trying to load data with custom cell renderers on grid in Safari 16.x and the grid renders each time very slowly when we scroll and is visually not good.

We have a data like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | C | 1 |
| A | X | C | 2 |
| A | X | D | 1 |
| A | X | D | 2 |
| A | X | D | 3 |
| B | X | E | 1 |

which we want to represent like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | C | 1 |
|  |  |  | 2 |
|  |  | -------- | -------- |
| A | X |  | 1 |
|  |  | D | 2 |
|  |  |  | 3 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| B | X | E | 1 |

C, D & E data is represented as a tree, for which we have used a custom cell renderer.

We tried enabling rowBuffer property but then it increases the # of DOM elements and grid response is not good. For ~100 row expand and collapse takes around 10sec to render.

Angular: 14.x
ag-grid: 28.x

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Carefully read the documentation on ag-grid's row virutalization, and make sure that you are not suppressing row virtualization.
- As you have seen, for best performance, you'll probably want to keep the rowbuffer as small as possible, but smooth rendering requires a decent sized rowbuffer, so you'll have to find the right size that balances performance vs rendering smoothness.
- Ultimately, the cause of your rendering issues is probably the amount of time that it takes to render your custom renderer. If you are using a "platform renderer", i.e. an Angular component, you'll have a lot more overhead than if you use a function. I'd work on making the custom renderer as lightweight as possible.